# What is the Proverb or Quotation?

Tags: idioms, proverbs

Is there a proverb or quote in English that has similarity with this one:

> "If the big two ox fight then the rubble gets the brunt."

This is a Maldivian idiom that explains how juniors get affected when elders quarrel or perhaps, when two ministers fight public gets the brunt etc.

Comment: Never heard something like that... :/

Comment: Well thank you all. I managed to browse the answer. shared here for the sake of the question. an african saying goes.. when two elephants fight the grass suffer.

Comment: Okay, feel free to post as an answer - click Answer this Question....

Comment: Yes, I knew there had to be one. Worded in more up-to-date way: "When two elephants fight, it is the grass that gets trampled."

Comment: Fairly closely related is 'When America sneezes, the world catches a cold'.

Comment: This is a great question. Welcome to ELU Ahmed. :)

Comment: Do you mean "rabble," not "rubble"? Don

Comment: @rhetorician *Rubble* would suffer under literal oxen, *rabble* under metaphorical ones.

Answer (score 1):

Elizabeth Knowles, *Little Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs* (2009) doesn't have any relevant proverbs that are native to English, but it does list a closely related proverb, drawn from Swahili:

> **When elephants fight, it is the grass that gets hurt.**
>
> the weak are likely to suffer as a result of the conflicts o the strong and powerful; African proverb (Swahili)

A somewhat similar proverb pointing to the idea that the actual combatants aren't the only ones injured in a fight is this one from Bartlett Whiting, *Early American Proverbs and Proverbial Phrases* (1977):

> When the members quarrel, the whole body must suffer.

And Wolfgang Mieder, *The Prentice-Hall Encyclopedia of World Proverbs* (1986) offers this proverb to sum up the implications of the preceding two:

> Innocence is no protection. *English*